# run into error parsing sub-millisecond timestamps in Julia

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp, julia

I was trying to query from our database, which contains sub-milisecond timestamps but Julia shows error parsing DateTime.

I tried converting the field using
`STR_TO_DATE(str,fmt)`
but didn't work.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Answer to this question found in Julialang discourse
(https://discourse.julialang.org/t/parsing-of-mysql-timestamps/77587/7?u=jerlich): using `DBInterface.execute(conn, sql; mysql_date_and_time=true)` instead of converting the field when query.